# How do i get only the max value of a column SQL

Tags: sql, count, max

i'm using this code

```
SELECT S.id_usuario, C.cnt
  FROM promos_usuarios S
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id_usuario, count(id_usuario) as cnt
                     FROM promos_usuarios 
                    GROUP BY id_usuario) C ON S.id_usuario = c.id_usuario
```

after using this code, i get this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcScd.png)

And i only need the max value of the column cnt, not the entire count, what can i do to make this work? i'm sorry if this doesnt make any sense, english isnt my main lenguage.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id_usuario, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM promos_usuarios 
GROUP BY id_usuario
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note all databases support `FETCH FIRST`.  Your database may use `SELECT TOP` or `LIMIT` or something else.

Comment: I noticed i didn't upload the picture of the table correctly, please check now!